# shortcode for displaying custom taxonomy with description in pods plugin - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

i have created a custom taxonomy named 'singer' using [pods plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) and inside that plugin i have defined a label named 'details'. what i want to do is to generate a short code in which returns that details. i have searched my way through lots of documentation, but could not find one.[image showing the custom field i have added inside the taxonomy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsC7y.png)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need it to be that complicated? (Meaning, do you need a plugin?)

Register a new taxonomy in your functions "singer":

```
            function taxonomies_init() {
                // create a new taxonomy
                register_taxonomy(
                    'singer',
                    'post',
                    array(
                        'label' => __( 'Singer' ),
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'singer' ),
                    )
                );
            }
            add_action( 'init', 'taxonomies_init' );
```

Register the shortcode:

```
            function showtax_func( $atts ) {

            if (is_single()) {
                $a = shortcode_atts( array(
                    'tax' => '',
                ), $atts );

                $termname = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),$a['tax'])[0]->name;
                return $termname;
                }

            }
            add_shortcode( 'show_tax', 'showtax_func' );
```

Use the shortcode like this: `[show_tax tax="singer"]`

You can add more taxonomies by expanding the first function by duplicating the `register_taxonomy()` function. And get any taxonomy with the shortcode by just changing the value of the taxonomy name.